# What are some different languages that express love in a cannibalistic ways and what are their significance?

Tags: list-of-languages

In my language, Albanian, we have phrases like "të hëngërsha zemrën" which if you translate it to English it's "(I wish) to eat the heart", **which is an expression of love**

I'm sure I read somewhere that there are some other languages that express love this way but I can't find anything. And are there any articles/books that might talk about how this difference might affect the way the people of the said languages see the world (something that I know I also read, that some people see the world differently purely based on what their languages have or lack)

Comment: Similar expressions of affection, usually directed at little children, exist in Romanian as well; e.g., *manca-l-ar mama*.

Comment: English does it too. “I could just eat you up!”.

Comment: German: "Ich hab Dich zum Fressen gern"

Comment: @Close voters: The first question in the title is clearly not opinion-based, as much as "What are languages that do X?"-type questions tend not to be so popular because they deviate from the site's aim a little bit. The second question also could be answered objectively if it's already been addressed by scholars (it might not be a good research question in linguistics proper but it's at least linguistics-adjacent; and there's no Anthropology SE). The body includes some iffy assumptions but that's no reason for closure.

Comment: Czech: Láskou by tě sežral (snědl). = I would eat you from/through my love.

Comment: @Nardog I was hoping for a scholarly by of answer because I can come up with random assumptions and examples myself, even English has "I could eat you up" and so on. I agree the body isn't good, I'm happy to change it. I read (don't know where) some languages don't have a word for a particular color (or something) which changed the way they interacted with the world. That's the kind of thing I was looking for